# Typescript does not error on compilation with create react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, react-scripts

I have set up a new project using `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` and I haven't changed any config settings.

If I type some code that has a TS error, my IDE (VS Code) will show the error. However, when I run start/build I do not get any compilation errors.

Further to this, `npm run build` does fail with the error when run on our GitLab CI/CD pipeline.

I have checked my TS versions, both in the project and where my global module is, both are the same version (4.1.3).

As I said, I haven't made any changes to what create react app has generated and I have tried creating a new project and get the same results. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT - To add to this, if I run `tsc` at the root I get the compilation errors, but `npm start` I do not.

EDIT 2 - This is my scripts in package.json (untouched from what CRA gives us)

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Comment: How do you run it locally? Using `npm run build`?

Comment: Yes, npm run build and npm run start both compile without errors when it should error. npm run build on GitLab CI/CD pipeline errors as it should.

Comment: Can you show us the section 'scripts' in your `package.json`?

Comment: @gbalduzzi I have added to question, they are untouched from what CRA gives us

Comment: Please provide more information about the error that you are confronting

Comment: @HamidOsouli this is for any code that produces a Typescript error, start/build do not report the error. console.log(typeof undefinedVar) for example.

Comment: @user195257 were you able to find a solution? facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I found I had to do this to see the `tsc` errors, but I don't like it

```
  "test": "tsc && react-scripts test",
```

Edit: Looks like this is, in-fact, the suggested workaround according to https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5626

Comment: i tested all the way back to react-scripts@2 and it seems the tests have never been compiled (with tsc), so however they are getting compiled/transpiled, the types are getting ignored